# Deference of 'response.body()' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview

I have a error. name is value string type. setText is string type but i have a error.

[image]

```
     Factory.getInstance().placeHolderModel().enqueue(new Callback<PlaceHolderModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PlaceHolderModel> call, Response<PlaceHolderModel> response) {
            textView.setText(response.body().name);
        }
```

Thank you very much

Your advice important for me

Comment: _Your advice important for me_ What is your question?

Comment: This is not an error, it is a warning produced by your IDE, that indicates that response might be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

it's just a warning not an error, to prevent that use

```
if (response.body != null ) {}
```

or use `annotation` at the header of your method `@NonNull`

> Denotes that a parameter, field or method return value can never
>   be null.

```
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<PlaceHolderModel> call, Response<PlaceHolderModel> response) {
```

[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/NonNull.html)